# Understanding a measure theory statement from Wikipedia

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, self-learning

I was reading the Measure (mathematics) page on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29

I was confused with one of their sections at the end, "Additivity". They were strengthening the condition of measure, countable additive.  They say for any set $I$ and any set of non-negative $r_i, i \in I,$ the sum of $r_i$ is defined to be supremum of all the sums of finitely many of them.

In this case is $r_i$ a set, or a number? If it is a number, why do we need the supremum? If it is a set, what do they mean by a non-negative set, or how to sum sets? Lastly, how does this strengthen countable additive condition of measure, does it weaken the disjoint condition? I had a similar confusion about the second statement they have in that same section, are $\lambda$ and $\kappa$ numbers or sets? What do they mean by $\lambda$ < $\kappa$, if they are sets? If possible, simple examples would help.

Comment: What is a nonnegative set $r_i$?

Comment: @Siminore I am wondering the same thing, I do not understand that part of the statement.

Comment: For clarity, the sentence should be "For any set of non-negative real numbers $r_i,\; i\in I$ ..." or something along those lines.

Comment: Ohh, so $r_i$ is a actual real number, then what is the purpose of the supremum, if we are only summing finitely many of them, why not just use max?

Comment: This is actually not a bad question. The wiki article is rather... elliptic. If you can read chapter 28 of *Problems and Theorems in Classical Set Theory* by Komjath and Totik it explains the issue: [GB preview](https://books.google.com/books?id=HGF3jkEaI-wC&pg=PA116).

Comment: @user77404 If $I$ is infinite, there are infinitely many finite subsets of $I$. We take the supremum of these infinitely many sums, one sum for each finite subset of $I$.